# JS enable disabled button if the conditions meet the requirements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu, textarea

I want to make a script which is checking if the textarea has more than 10 characters in it, and if the custom dropdown menu's `textContent` is not equals with `Choose one`. As you can see it's working but after you select an option from the menu, the `Post` button is still disabled, and only will be enabled if you write a letter in the textarea. Is there any way to set the `Post` button immediately enabled after the user selected an option?

**CODE:**

```js
var options = document.getElementById('option-selected-choose-one'); // This is the custom select box
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cpmsbtndbld').attr('disabled',true); // This is the submit button
    $('#post_input_textarea').keyup(function(){
        if(options.textContent != 'Choose one' && $(this).val().length > 10) { // If the select tag's value is not `Choose one` and the textarea has more characters than 10
            $('#cpmsbtndbld').attr('disabled', false); // Enable the submit button
        } else {
            $('#cpmsbtndbld').attr('disabled',true); // Stay disabled
        }
    })
});
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: UM, run the logic onchange of the select....

Comment: I have already tried that and nothing happaned.

Comment: Well you can not use `$(this).val().length` if you planned on reusing the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to @Amith's answer, I reused it and made a new function and now it looks like this, and works properly:

```js
var options = document.getElementById('option-selected-choose-one'); // This is the custom select box
function checkConstraints(){
  if(options.textContent != 'Choose one' && $(this).val().length > 10) { // If the select tag's value is not `Choose one` and the textarea has more characters than 10
    $('#cpmsbtndbld').attr('disabled', false); // Enable the submit button
  } else {
    $('#cpmsbtndbld').attr('disabled',true); // Stay disabled
  }
}
function enableSub(){
    if(options.textContent != 'Choose one') { // If the select tag's value is not `Choose one` and the textarea has more characters than 10
      $('#cpmsbtndbld').attr('disabled', false); // Enable the submit button
    } else {
      $('#cpmsbtndbld').attr('disabled',true); // Stay disabled
    }
  }
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cpmsbtndbld').attr('disabled',true); // This is the submit button
  $("#option-selected-choose-one").change(enableSub);
  $(".drop_elem").click(enableSub);
  $('#post_input_textarea').keyup(checkConstraints);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the function only triggers on keyup event on the textarea.

Also add it to the dropdown:

```
$("#drop").change(function () {   
        //logic
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check your constraints to enable post button, on both selection and typing in text area.

```js
var options = document.getElementById('option-selected-choose-one'); // This is the custom select box

function checkConstraints(){
  if(options.textContent != 'Choose one' && $('#post_input_textarea').val().length > 10) { // If the select tag's value is not `Choose one` and the textarea has more characters than 10
    $('#cpmsbtndbld').attr('disabled', false); // Enable the submit button
  } else {
    $('#cpmsbtndbld').attr('disabled',true); // Stay disabled
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cpmsbtndbld').attr('disabled',true); // This is the submit button
  $("#option-selected-choose-one").on("change", checkConstraints);
  $('#post_input_textarea').keyup(checkConstraints);
});
```

Comment: @epascarello It's indeed not gonna work, but it helped me a lot, so I could work with it and I could solve my problem.

Comment: @epascarello I didn't see that there is a `this` in the function. Fixed that.